# How do I fit a curve around a set of points with Octave?

Tags: octave, bezier

I have a set of points scattered on the xy plane. I want to find a curve that encloses them. Preferably a spline curve. I only find curve fitting examples on line. I want a closed loop around the points.

Comment: how do you define a spline that encloses all ? From all side ? you can have corner cases difficult to manage.

Comment: I see what you're saying. In this case, enclosing most of the points will work. I'd like a parameterized curve. Your suggestion of convhull should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use convhull to find the external envelope to your set

```
x = rand (1, 30);
y = rand (1, 30);
hold on;
plot (x, y, "r*");
H=convhull(x,y)
plot(x(H),y(H));
axis ([0,1,0,1]);
```

Comment: That should do it! Thanks